# Journey Builder: Email send activity error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In the Journey that I built is based on DE and giving error while triggering the email activity. Attached are the screenshots of the error

1. [image]
2. [image]

In journey setting, I have used 'Use email attribute from entry source'

Can anyone please help me understand this issue so that I can resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Could you also provide the relevant code from your Email where you try to access that data?

Comment: ~ and the call that starts the journey?

Comment: Hello @DonL, Source to lick off the journey is the DE and scheduled by automation. I really don't think email is the problem as for some of the data in DE, it actually sent the email. And on top of it if I will try to send the user-initiated email it also works. Please let me know if you still would like to see the code. Thanks

Comment: Appears to be an issue with the default email address. Is it possible that these contacts don’t have a value for the selected field under Journey Settings > Default Email Address?

Comment: Found the issue, Thanks to @Eliot. The issue was - Email content (amp script) used in the journey is accessing a DE which is not in the BU. We found this through SFMC Object finder chrome extension(very helpful).